# What does if(false) in php mean?

Tags: php, wordpress

Today, I decided to download wordpress and the first file that I have come across is wp-admin/install.php. the first thing in the file is this:

```
// Sanity check.
if ( false ) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Error: PHP is not running</title>
</head>
<body class="wp-core-ui">
    <p id="logo"><a href="https://wordpress.org/">WordPress</a></p>
    <h1>Error: PHP is not running</h1>
    <p>WordPress requires that your web server is running PHP. Your server does not have PHP installed, or PHP is turned off.</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
```

Now I am kind of wondering, What is `if( false )` ? and how does it mean that the user is not running php on their server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PHP is running on the server, the statement inside `if ( false )` will be skipped, because this equates to *FALSE* or its like `if(0)` .

But in such cases that PHP compiler does not exist, the server will parse all html codes inside that statement ,(saying PHP is not running).

It's a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because condition is never true when being executed by PHP server, in consecuence PHP is running in the server. Otherwise you will see the HTML that say PHP is not running. Because php code is what is not being executed in this case.